# Convert SQL query set into Django Model Query-set?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to convert  the following query of SQL into Django Query-set:-

> select sum(amount) from accounts_order where status='Pending' and
> customer_id=1;

here is my models.py file

from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """All Customers details goes here"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Customer."""

        verbose_name = 'Customer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customers'

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Customer."""
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    """All order details goes here.It has OneToMany relationship with  Customer"""
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Done', 'Done'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    bill_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS, null=False)
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=255, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Order."""

        verbose_name = 'Order'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Orders'

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Order."""
        return self.bill_name
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) here:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Order.objects.filter(
    status='Pending', customer_id=1
).aggregate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))['total_amount']
```